# Global.asax not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, import, global-asax

I'm planning to utilize the global import for System.Data package. After I added the

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
```

in the markup of global.asax

In one of my class I removed 'Using System.Data' on top of the code.
I built the global.asax and the class.

But instead of built successful, I received error

> The name 'CommandType' does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to import the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace too, assuming that's a command object it's failing on.

**EDIT**

If you want certain namespaces available to all pages, try adding them in the web.config instead:

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.IO" />
        <add namespace="ProjectName.Classes" />
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: i tried the code above, the web.config doesn't recognize the <pages> tags and <namespaces> tags. :-(

Comment: the `pages` section goes under the `system.web` section.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you misunderstand what global.asax does.

It doesn't provide for global Import/Using statements.

Read up on it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2027ewzw.aspx) and even better a [Stackoverflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340572/global-asax-in-asp-net)

Global.asax allows you to handle application/session lifecyle events.

You will need to include your Import Namespace in the files that you are using calls to the System.Data namespace