# Using the Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have just read about Global.asax (as you can tell, I am new to asp.net) I'm wondering would it be a good idea to use the Session_End method that comes with the Global class to redirect a user when the session has been ended? Or just do IF statements on page loads to check if any values are null?

Also, how is the Global class called? Is it what is ran in the background of every application or do you have to specifically call a method from the class in order to utilize it?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question regarding redirect from Session_End:
[Redirecting to another page on session end event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565791/redirecting-to-another-page-on-session-end-event)

To answer your second question regarding how the global.asax class is used:
[What is the purpose of global.asax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340572/what-is-the-purpose-of-global-asax-in-asp-net)

Good luck!