# How to read ASP .Net cookie in WebForms ASP .NET site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, cookies, shared

I'm migrating a lot of WebForms applications (old **site** template). I'm develop a login in ASP .Net Core and create a shared cookie for several web applications, following this:

https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security/data-protection/compatibility/cookie-sharing.html

It's ok with new apps, but old web site ASP .NET don't use Startup.cs class

How to validate this cookie new ASP .NET Core in old Web Form application?

Thanks!

Comment: Upps, i forget "Core" in title ==> How to read ASP .Net CORE cookie in WebForms ASP .NET site

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do something in the equivalent "Startup.cs" from Core to Webforms, you can use the Global.asax class.  Here's some more info: [What is the purpose of global.asax in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340572/what-is-the-purpose-of-global-asax-in-asp-net)