# Why doesn't C# .Net Framework Web Form Application have a Main function, or Program.cs

Tags: c#, .net, program-entry-point

I was following some tutorials and created a new C# .Net Framework 4.6 Application as a web form type. When working on the project I noticed it doesn't have a Main Function to add logic too, it also doesn't have a program.cs, yet it is able to build fine. Why is that, I was under the impression that all C# programs need a main function to start as there entry point, and have seen multiple resources on the web stating that(https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/main-method-in-c-sharp, https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/basic/main-method.php).

If we don't need it what is replacing it, and serving as the code entry point. I also noticed that there is no program.cs what is the reason for this. I have been researching but I find the answers posted very contradictory to what is actually in the code.

Comment: All programs need to have an entry point. By default this is a static function called `Main` (although it doesn't have to be in a class called `Program`: that's just convention), but you can configure the compiler to call any method you like as the entry point. Project -> Properties -> Application -> Startup object. My guess is either that this is set to something different (or it just defaults to something different in a webforms project), or the main method is being generated when the project is compiled, so you don't see it in the source code.

Comment: The very first line of the article in your first link is "The Main method is the entry point of a C# console application or windows application." A Web form is not a console or windows desktop application; it is a web page

Comment: so where does it start from when it is type web page?

Comment: It doesn't start, per se. It becomes a DLL that has all the code of the app, and the DLL is loaded by a program (such as IIS web server) that is already running. When someone makes a request to IIS, IIS calls different functions inside the DLL(s) comprising the app. You could consider that an ASP.NET webforms app is "just a plugin for IIS that makes it behave in a very specific way". IIS might call certain functions at certain times, such as "when it loads the dll" which is like a startup, and would be the closest thing to a Main method corollary in a console app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the old (.NET Framework) it runs in process - the startup code is for some reason that are MOSTLY historical (ASP pre .NET) in a file GLOBAL.ASAX

[What is the purpose of global.asax in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340572/what-is-the-purpose-of-global-asax-in-asp-net)

Again, this really goes back to asp.net mvc following up on the concepts of asp (pre .net). It is rectified in the Core versions where basically a program starts for the application.

Comment: so if I wanted to add some that I would normally put in the main, where would I put it, would the global.asax be the correct place?

Comment: Why don't you just ask "I have this code X where should I put it in my asp net project?". How can we accurately say "yes, that code you say you have that we can't see, should definitely go in global.asax" ?

Comment: the global fiule has event handlers for start and stop. Obviously one of them (start) is where startup code goes.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET applications do have an entry point but in a roundabout way.

For a .NETFramework ASP.NET Web Forms app, you are usually going to have a `Global.aspx.cs` file with an `Application_Start` method that does your application configuration (routes etc).

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178473(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#life-cycle-events-and-the-globalasax-file

Answer (score 1):

A web form or app is not a "program". It is a collection of pages and other classes that are referenced by the underlying ASP.NET service.

There are many more details to the ASP.NET ecosystem, but the main reason is because a site is not a "program" that needs an entry point.  Only console apps and windows apps need an entry point.